# It didn't want to install in my virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.5

```
(goat) ┌─╼ [~/Projects/Personal_Projects/Goat_TDD_Project/superlists]
└╼ pip3 install django-extensions
Collecting django-extensions
  Using cached django_extensions-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.2 in /home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from django-extensions)
Installing collected packages: django-extensions
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/jeremie/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions'
```

I am trying to understand why I have this issue when I try to install `django-extensions`. Yet I am in the virtualenv (wrapper) `goat`, but it didn't want to install in it. How could I fix that?

### Update

With `ls -ld` on the virtualenv, I got

```
drwxrwxr-x 7 jeremie jeremie 4096 Sep  9 17:10 goat
```

Comment: Have you tried making a fresh virtualenv and pip installing the package there?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur of you created your virtualenv as root.

If so, to fix it, you can run the command:

```
sudo chown -R your_username:your_username path/to/virtuaelenv/
```

**update**

The other reason that this can occur is when you have installed pip (or pip3 in this case) as root.

From your error you can see that it is trying to install the package outside of your virtualenv, at the root level.

To verify this, check the permissions of your pip installation:

```
user@host:~$ which pip3 
/usr/local/bin/pip3
user@host:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root ... etc, etc
```

Or just run the one-liner:

```
ls -l `which pip3`
```

You can fix this by uninstalling pip3, and reinstalling it without using the sudo command.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate, but it is not my real problem

Comment: @J.Doe did you try running the command above? Can you also run `ls -ld /path/to/virtualenv` and update your question with the output?

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Ok I will update my question

Comment: @J.Doe actually it looks like the problem is that pip was installed as root. That is why it is trying to install the package outside the virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use 'pip3' inside a virtualenv.

So just use:

```
  pip install django-extensions
```

after activating the virtualenv